# Text Prediction Using Android

Tags: android, text, prediction

I want to develop an application where the user will write on the screen of an android touchscreen device and hints for the words will be generated above in a widget. When the user clicks on a hint it will be placed above in a Textview. I plan to use gestureoverlayview class to design the writing area.

I have my own recognizer module.Hence I wont use the Predict module present in Samsung android.

My question is , which widget should I use for displaying the hints ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="10">
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:layout_weight="3">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Hello"
         />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="3">

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:layout_weight="6">


    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="6"
    android:layout_weight="1">


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What you have done from your side ??

Comment: he asked question on SO ...

Comment: @Garry I have developed an initial layout for the purpose. I have created the buttons and textviews. I have searched for the kind of widget i need to use. I am not sure if its ListView. Thats exactly why I asked the question. may be I have not been able to put my question properly. Hope you can suggest a class name ??

Comment: @Selvin 
Isnt 'asking a question in SO' a little better than making irrelevant remarks ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoCompleteTextView did the trick